# How to create a reuseable audio player component with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, audio

I am trying to create a reusable audio player component that I can use throughout my project. I followed this [tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/building-an-audio-player-app-with-angular-and-rxjs/) in creating the audio player itself.

Now the problem is that I decided to make the audio player a component on its own that can be rendered in other components and then pass the audio url using @Input. It works fine with one instance of the component, but once another instance of the component is created, both rendered instances of the component behaves the same, they play the same file, the button on one component affects the other component i.e if I press the play button on one audio player, the second one will also play with the same file.

Here are the relevant code.

audio.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { StreamState } from './stream-state';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AudioService {
  constructor() {}

  private stop$ = new Subject();
  private audioObject: HTMLAudioElement = new Audio();

  private audioEvents: Array<string> = [
    'ended',
    'error',
    'play',
    'playing',
    'pause',
    'timeupdate',
    'canplay',
    'loadedmetadata',
    'loadstart',
  ];
  private state: StreamState = {
    playing: false,
    readableCurrentTime: '',
    readableDuration: '',
    duration: undefined,
    currentTime: undefined,
    canplay: false,
    error: false,
    mute: false,
  };
  private streamObservable(url) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      // Play audio
      this.audioObject.src = url;
      this.audioObject.load();
      this.audioObject.play();

      const handler = (event: Event) => {
        this.updateStateEvents(event);
        observer.next(event);
      };
      this.addEvents(this.audioObject, this.audioEvents, handler);
      return () => {
        this.audioObject.pause();
        this.audioObject.currentTime = 0;

        this.removeEvent(this.audioObject, this.audioEvents, handler);
        this.resetState();
      };
    });
  }
  private addEvents(obj, events, handler) {
    events.forEach(event => {
      obj.addEventListener(event, handler);
    });
  }

  private removeEvent(obj, events, handler) {
    events.forEach(event => {
      obj.removeEventListener(event, handler);
    });
  }

  playStream(url) {
    return this.streamObservable(url).pipe(takeUntil(this.stop$));
  }

  play() {
    this.audioObject.play();
  }
  pause() {
    this.audioObject.pause();
  }
  stop() {
    this.stop$.next();
  }
  mute() {
    this.audioObject.volume = 0;
    this.state.mute = true;
  }
  unmute() {
    this.audioObject.volume = 1;
    this.state.mute = false;
  }
  seekTo(seconds) {
    this.audioObject.currentTime = seconds;
  }

  formatTime(time: number, format: string = 'mm:ss') {
    const momentTime = time * 1000;
    return moment.utc(momentTime).format(format);
  }

  private stateChange: BehaviorSubject<StreamState> = new BehaviorSubject(this.state);

  private updateStateEvents(event: Event): void {
    switch (event.type) {
      case 'canplay':
        this.state.duration = this.audioObject.duration;
        this.state.readableDuration = this.formatTime(this.state.duration);
        this.state.canplay = true;
        break;

      case 'playing':
        this.state.playing = true;
        break;

      case 'pause':
        this.state.playing = false;
        break;

      case 'timeupdate':
        this.state.currentTime = this.audioObject.currentTime;
        this.state.readableCurrentTime = this.formatTime(this.state.currentTime);
        break;

      case 'error':
        this.resetState();
        this.state.error = true;
        break;
    }
    this.stateChange.next(this.state);
  }

  private resetState() {
    this.state = {
      playing: false,
      readableCurrentTime: '',
      readableDuration: '',
      duration: undefined,
      currentTime: undefined,
      canplay: false,
      error: false,
      mute: false,
    };
  }

  getState(): Observable<StreamState> {
    return this.stateChange.asObservable();
  }
```

audioplayer.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { StreamState } from './stream-state';
import { AudioService } from './audio.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-audio-player',
  templateUrl: './audio-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./audio-player.component.scss'],
})
export class AudioPlayerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() audioUrl: string;
  @Input() ID: string;

  state: StreamState;

  constructor(private audioService: AudioService) {
    this.audioService.getState().subscribe(state => {
      this.state = state;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.audioUrl);
    this.playStream(this.audioUrl);
    this.pause();
  }
  playStream(url) {
    this.audioService.playStream(url).subscribe(events => {
      // console.log(events);
    });
  }

  pause() {
    this.audioService.pause();
  }
  play() {
    this.audioService.play();
  }
  stop() {
    this.audioService.stop();
  }
  mute() {
    this.audioService.mute();
  }
  unmute() {
    this.audioService.unmute();
  }
  onSliderChangeEnd(change) {
    this.audioService.seekTo(change.value);
  }
}
```

stream-state.ts

```
export interface StreamState {
  playing: boolean;
  readableCurrentTime: string;
  readableDuration: string;
  duration: number | undefined;
  currentTime: number | undefined;
  canplay: boolean;
  error: boolean;
  mute: boolean;
}
```

example.component.html

```
<div>
<app-audio-player audioUrl="audiofile.mp3"></app-audio-player>
<app-audio-player audioUrl="newaudio.mp3"></app-audio-player>
</div>
```

Please what can I do to make sure that each instance of the audioplayer component is independent.
Thank you.

Update.
This is the link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jfhr7x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to the stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found (not sure if its the best way) is to provide the service locally or only to the component and not in root.
The reason both players play the same song at the same time is because the service is provided in root, so one instance is shared through out the whole project. And when you assign a new song URL it only updates the URL in the global service.

To provide service only to component, remove the

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

in **audio.service.ts**.

Then add the AudioService as a provider directly in the **audio-player.component.ts** as followed:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-audio-player',
  templateUrl: './audio-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./audio-player.component.scss'],
  providers: [AudioService],
})
```

Also regarding the current state of the files, the first audio file does not exist anymore so it must be updated for the component to work.

[Forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7esgzh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Faudio-player%2Faudio.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Faudio-player%2Faudio-player.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please update this example on https://stackblitz.com/. We would be able to help you better.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the link here, once the sample code is ready.

Comment: This is the link to the stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jfhr7x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html.....
 I could not get the design properly over there